# Updating recyclerview results in activity being turned on twice

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, cardview

Hi I have implemented in my app a recyclerview. After clicking on an element in recyclerview an activity is initiated. However I have noticed a problem that after updating the recyclerview, after clicking on an element, a certain activity is initiated two times.

Here is the code that I use to initiate the recyclerview:

```
private void initViews(){


    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new customadaptertest(stoiska, logoarray,getApplicationContext(), namestoiska);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if(child != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                int position = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
                Intent showmap = new Intent(Search_Engine.this, (Class) activities.get(position));
                startActivity(showmap);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) stoiska.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }

    });
```

This initViews() is used in onCreate as well as in a button that after clicking will use different arguments to create a recyclerview. The recyclerview list is updated correctly, but the problem is that each activity is turned on twice

update, changed my adapter but now the activity won't turn on at all:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    viewHolder.tv_country.setText(countries.get(i));
    viewHolder.nazwafirmy.setText(countries2.get(i));
    viewHolder.tv_country.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent showmap = new Intent(v.getContext(), (Class) activities.get(i));
            v.getContext().startActivity(showmap);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the certain activity? The activity you intened to open?

Comment: it is a listview. A person will be able to press a button after which a listview opens. He then selects out of available options one that interests him. on selecting this particular options a new recyclerview should be created replacing the old one

Answer (score 0):

If OnClick is the only functionality you need, you should try adding a `onClickListener` interface to the adapter itself.

So here in your `CustomAdapterTest` class, inside the `onBindViewHolder()` method set the onclick functionality to root view of the row.

Ex. Consider the rootRowLayout to be `mCardView`

`holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new OnClick....`

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't have to write all this complicated stuff with catching touch events. 
Create listener class

```
public interface RecyclerListener {

    void onClick();
    void onLongClick();

}
```

Put this listener into adapter constructor

```
 public HistoryAdapter(List<YourData> Datas, RecyclerListener listener){
    this.orderlistDatas=orderlistDatas;
    this.listener = listener
}
```

In your onBindViewHolder method inside adapter call

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickLisnter
holder.itemView.setOnLongLickListener
```

Implement this listener to your activity where you you call adapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your adapter class

```
@Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     holder.stoiska.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent showmap = new Intent(Search_Engine.this, (Class) activities.get(position));
                startActivity(showmap);
             }
     }
}
```

Comment: i put in my adapter this but it the activity wont turn on at all:@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        viewHolder.tv_country.setText(countries.get(i));
        viewHolder.nazwafirmy.setText(countries2.get(i));
        viewHolder.tv_country.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent showmap = new Intent(v.getContext(), (Class) activities.get(i));
                v.getContext().startActivity(showmap);
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener `interface` back to the `Activity` you're clicking on the `RecyclerView` from.

So in your `RecyclerViewAdapter` add:

```
private onRecyclerViewItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(onRecyclerViewItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
  this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

public interface onRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
  void onItemClickListener(View view, int position);
}
```

Then in your `ViewHolder` (which I add as an inner-class inside the adapter) add an `onClickListener` to the item you want to click on i.e. `tv_country`. An example `ViewHolder` would be:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView tv_country;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.tv_country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
        this.tv_country.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClick(View v) {
       if (mItemClickListener != null) {
         mItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(v, getAdapterPosition());
       }
    }
}
```

And then simply in your Activity when your initialize your `Adapter`, you can now call the `OnItemClickListener` on your `RecyclerView`

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.onRecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {
                                switch (v.getId()) {
                                    case R.id.tv_country:
                                       Intent showmap = new Intent(Search_Engine.this, (Class) activities.get(position));
            startActivity(showmap);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

So what this has done is, pass the view and position from your adapter back to your Activity where the list of activities is, you then use the position you passed from the adapter to get the correct activity in your list. This should take you to the correct corresponding event.

Further Reading:

- [Set a click listener to a RecyclerView](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)